# Speeding up Python code that has to go through entire list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, while-loop

I have a problem where I need to (pretty sure at least) go through the entire list to solve. The question is to figure out the largest number of consecutive numbers in a list that add up to another (greater) element in that list. If there aren't any then we just take the largest value in the list as the candidate summation and 1 as the largest consecutive number of elements.

My general code works, but not too well for large lists (>500,000 elements). I am just looking for tips as to how I could approach the problem differently. My current approach:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
candidate_sum = L[-1]
largest_count = 1
N = len(L)
i = 0

while i < N - 1:
    s = L[i]
    j = 0
    while s <= (N - L[i + j + 1]):
        j += 1
        s += L[i+j]
        if s in L and (j+1) > largest_count:
             largest_count = j+1
             candidate_sum = s
    i+=1
```

In this case, the answer would be [1,2,3,4] as they add up to 10 and the length is 4 (obviously this example L is a very simple example).

I then made it faster by changing the initial while loop condition to:

```
while i < (N-1)/largest_count
```

Not a great assumption, but basic thinking that the distribution of numbers is somewhat uniform, so two numbers on the second half of the list are on average bigger than the final number in the list, and therefore are disqualified.

I'm just looking for:

- possible bottlenecks
- suggestions as to different approaches to try

Comment: You need to define your problem more precisely. Is list always sorted and monotonic? Will there be any gaps in them? Best solution will differ depending on exact problem statement.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski list is always sorted, all elements are unique so the list is strictly increasing and yes, there are gaps between consecutive numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Strictly ascending: no duplication of elements or subsequences, single possible solution
- Arbitrary-spaced: no arithmetical shortcuts, has to operate brute-force

Efficient C implementation using pointer arithmetic, quasi polymorphic over numeric types:

```c
#define TYPE int

int max_subsum(TYPE arr [], int size) {
   int max_length = 1;

   TYPE arr_fst = * arr;
   TYPE* num_ptr = arr;

   while (size --) {
      TYPE num = * num_ptr++;

      TYPE* lower = arr;
      TYPE* upper = arr;

      TYPE sum = arr_fst;
      int length = 1;

      for (;;) {
         if (sum > num) {
            sum -= * lower++;
            -- length;
         }
         else if (sum < num) {
            sum += * ++upper;
            ++ length;
         }
         else {
            if (length > max_length) {
               max_length = length;
            }

            break;
         }
      }
   }

   return max_length;
}
```

The main loop over the `num`s is parallelizable. Relatively straight-forward translation into Python 3 using the dynamic-array list type for `arr` and the `for each` loop:

```
def max_subsum(arr):
   max_len = 1
   arr_fst = arr[0]

   for n in arr:
      lower = 0
      upper = 0

      sum = arr_fst

      while True:
         if sum > n:
            sum -= arr[lower]
            lower += 1
         elif sum < n:
            upper += 1
            sum += arr[upper]
         else:
            sum_len = upper - lower + 1

            if sum_len > max_len:
               max_len = sum_len

            break

   return max_len
```

This `max_subsum` is a partial function; Python lists can be empty. The algorithm is appropriate for C-like compiled imperative languages offering fast indexing and statically typed arithmetic. Both are comparatively expensive in Python. A (totally defined) algorithm rather similar to yours, using the `set` data type for more performant universal quantification, and avoiding Python's dynamically typed arithmetic, can be more efficiently interpreted:

```
def max_subsum(arr):
   size = len(arr)
   max_len = 0

   arr_set = set(arr)

   for i in range(size):
      sum = 0
      sum_len = 0

      for j in range(i, size):
         sum_mem = sum + arr[j]

         if num_mem not in arr_set:
            break

         sum = sum_mem
         sum_len += 1

      if sum_len > max_len:
         max_len = sum_len

   return max_len
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to ignore the possibility of a changing target value, and let you figure that out, but to answer your question "is there a faster way to do it?" Yes: by using cumulative sums and some math to eliminate one of your loops.

```
import numpy as np

L = np.random.randint(0,100,100)
L.sort()
cum_sum = np.cumsum(L)

start = 0
end = 0

target = 200

while 1:
    total = cum_sum [end-1] - (cum_sum [start-1] if start else 0)
    if total == target:
        break
    elif total < target:
        end += 1
    elif total > target:
        start += 1
    if end >= len(L):
        raise ValueError('something informative')
```

Comment: It seems this code does not handle the case when no solution is possible. You need to ensure that `start <= end` and `end < len(L)` at the end of every loop.

Comment: @LakshayGarg `start` should not be able to be greater than `end` ever because `cum_sum` is sorted if `L` is sorted. If they are equal `end` will be incremented on the next iteration. I fixed the no solution issue, and a math error..

Comment: @LakshayGarg actually the condition is that all `L` is > 0, not that `L` is sorted, but that does hold for the example I gave.. It is also somewhat necessary for this method to work (without significant modification).